# wall unit, wall outlet, or wall jack?

Tags: vocabulary

Which of the following options is correct?

The phone is plugged into a wall unit / wall jack / wall outlet.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: This may very well depend on who you're talking to, as well as local/regional conventional usage. Here in the NYC area, *I* would invariably say 'jack', because I'm somewhat technically oriented - but I have some non-technical acquaintances who say 'outlet', and others who follow my usage and say 'jack'.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin What about a wall unit?

Comment: I have never heard that used. In this area, a "wall unit" is another - somewhat dated - term for what is now generally called a "Home Entertainment Center" (e.g., an integrated piece of furniture affixed to the wall that has space for a TV, stereo, record player/tape player/CD player/etc., storage for recordings, possibly bookshelves as well).

Comment: It's hard to give you a good answer because you don't say what you're trying to mean.  Are you talking about [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1230&bih=828&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=4R_fWqD-M-yV_Qaq_rW4Ag&q=phone+wall+jack&oq=phone+wall+jack&gs_l) or [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1230&bih=828&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=5x_fWvrnOOapggfcsp84&q=electrical+outlet&oq=electrical+outlet&gs_l)?

Comment: I am not talking about electrical supplies; can "outlet" be used?

Comment: I usually call them *wall **sockets***. To me, a *wall **unit*** is a large piece of furniture with shelves and/or cupboards, And a ***jack*** is the male audio/video connector on either end of the lead for something like an electric guitar - both ends of which plug in to *jack sockets* (one on the guitar itself, the other on the amplifier).

Comment: Indeed, in the UK, _socket_ is the usual word for anything that you plug something vaguely electrical into - whether power, phone, internet, or headphone.

Comment: _unit_ is a generic word that can be applied to almost anything, not unlike _item_. Consequently, It may be an acceptable term, but it's unlikely to be the best one. And what do you mean by "not talking about electrical supplies"? What else do you plug a phone into? (I don't know what came up when you clicked on those links that @stangdon left, but, where I'm from in the US, and in the context of plugging something into the wall, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlJPlm.jpg) is a jack, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrzlCm.jpg) is an outlet.)

Comment: In general, an (electrical) wall socket or outlet are the same thing. A jack, however, is for telephones or computers, but not for lamps or other luminaries. None of these are units, really.

Comment: The word "port" also works just fine.  It's more common when using the proper name, or an "RJ11 Port."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean one of these (increasingly rare) things:

[image]

As the comments indicate, this may vary considerably by region.  I grew up calling it

> a **(tele)phone jack**,

or

> a **(tele)phone socket**

I would understand what you meant by "wall jack" or "wall outlet" but neither sounds idiomatic.  However a "wall unit" sounds like a piece of furniture integrated into the wall.  Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The term *outlet* suggests a one-way flow, which is appropriate for a power source, but not for conversations.